# store procedure with multiple string parameter out mssql

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i'm having trouble retriving multiple parameter in store procedure

here is my code

```
enter code here

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getdataComport", cnn);


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // set up the parameters
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ComName", SqlDbType.Text).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BaudRate", SqlDbType.Text).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@batchName", SqlDbType.Text).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                // open connection and execute stored procedure
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int retval = (int)cmd.Parameters["@retParam"].Value;
                // read output value from @NewId
                comname = cmd.Parameters["@ComName"].Value.ToString();
                Baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@BaudRate"].Value);
                batchname = cmd.Parameters["@batchName"].Value.ToString();

                cnn.Close();
```

here is my store procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getdataComport]
    @ComName varchar(20) out,
    @BaudRate int out,
    @batchName varchar(20) out 
as


begin 
        select top 1 
                @ComName=ComPortName,
                @BaudRate=BaudRateName,
                @batchName=BatchName
        from tblComPort
        order by Valuedate desc
end
```

i've always getting error when i run it 
can anyone help me on this?

Comment: When you're getting error, you should post error details.

Comment: Looking at your stored procedure, you don't need out parameters here. You need to have `select` query. And you can get the data by using SqlDataReader by doing `var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`. Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: "i've always getting error when i run it " - *what error?* please tell us exactly what it says, and on which line it says it

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it isn't *wrong* to use `out` parameters for this, note; both approaches have valid use-cases

Comment: It's not wrong. But there is a better and clearer approach which can be used.

Comment: "string [] 0 is the error ". sorry i forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by getting the data types right:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ComName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BaudRate", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@batchName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And remove:

```
int retval = (int)cmd.Parameters["@retParam"].Value;
```

Because: that doesn't exist.

Note that `ExecuteNonQuery` *has* an `int` return value directly, but it isn't the same as the `return` value from a sproc; for that, you need a parameter with `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`. This is moot since your sproc doesn't have a `return` value.